# Does the Microsoft Graph API also limit total SharePoint list items to only 5000?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, limitations, graph-api

I have found a couple blogs indicating that the Graph API uses the REST API, which would imply that the same 5000 item limit applies.  But I cannot find any o[fficial Microsoft documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/listitem_list) identifying the limit.

Answer (score 1):

**In short**, YES!

The `Microsoft Graph` is a **RESTful web API**  that runs into the 5000 item limits.

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed!  So, the limitation is because of the RESTful-ness?  I was under the impression that it was an extension of the SharePoint view threshold of 5000...